# Programmatically open a view eclipse view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, treeviewer

I want to programmatically open an eclipse view, I tried this code:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(view.ID);
```

It opens the view but it only instantiate it once.. I need to open a view on a double click on a file in the package explorer, the only way I found so far is opening it in the editor constructor ( a custom editor, btw if anybody knows how to open a view on double click on a file in the package explorer I'm all ears). To populate the view (tree view) I use data from a file, it works fine the first time I open it but then it does not refresh its content.

Can I perhaps access the view class object and manipulate somehow (get the tree viewer object maybe)? The perfect way to do this would be to open the view on a double click directly in the file that I need to render but I didn't find how, can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is really a read-only editor.  There shouldn't be any reason that you couldn't implement an editor with dummy save() and saveAs() implementations.  You'd get the double-click support you want in any navigation view.

Comment: So you're saying that I should add another editor which implements the tree viewer in an editor? I thought about that but it would mean that it will be opened separately from my editor.. it's a rather extreme solution I would rather not do it like that since all I need is find a way to "restart" the tree viewer programmatically

Comment: You didn't mention anything about already having an editor, only about opening a view by double clicking a file in a navigator view.  If you have an editor and a view already open then you can have your EditorPart call a method on the ViewerPart to refresh itself with a file reference passed in the method call.  Both the editor and viewer should have access to the Activator class in your plugin and can communicate via that Activator.

Comment: I figured that I should use the editor since it's opened at double click, but I never thought about using the activator. Thank you for your help.